Inequalities for the Dirichlet eta function at non-trivial Riemann zeta zeros.
I am interested in these inequalities for sufficiently large $n$:
$$\Large \left(\Re\left(\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} x^{\log (k) c}\right)\right)^2 \leq \left( \Re\left(x^{\log \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) c}\right)\right)^2\tag{1}$$
$$\Large \left( \Im\left(\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} x^{\log (k) c}\right)\right)^2 \leq \left( \Im\left(x^{\log \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) c}\right)\right)^2\tag{2}$$
$\Large n=1,2,3,...$
The novelty is the modification:
$$x^{c \log \left(n\right)} \rightarrow x^{c \log \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$

Do they hold only for the non-trivial zeta zeros assuming the Riemann hypothesis?

$$z=\rho _j = \text{a non-trivial Riemann zeta zero.}$$
$$c \geq \frac{\Im(z)}{\pi }$$
$$\Large x=e^{-\frac{z}{c}}$$
For inequality $(1)$ Mathematica 14
(*start*)
Clear[n, sigma, t, k, r]
sigma = r;
Reduce[((Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)*
         Exp[-(sigma + I*t)/(t/Pi)]^(Log[k]*(t/Pi)), {k, 1, n}] + 
       Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)*
         Exp[-(sigma - I*t)/(t/Pi)]^(Log[k]*(t/Pi)), {k, 1, n}])/
     2)^2 <= (((-1)^(n + 1)*
        Exp[-((sigma + I*t))/(t/Pi)]^(Log[
            n + 1/2]*(t/Pi)) + (-1)^(n + 1)*
        Exp[-((sigma - I*t))/(t/Pi)]^(Log[n + 1/2]*(t/Pi)))/2)^2]
(*end*)

gives the following output that is very long, starting:



